# How to refer to parameter as a view controller instantiating a protocol in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have a custom protocol I'm using to define some behavior for some of my view controllers:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    ...
}
```

I want to be able to declare the type of parameter in my function as UIViewControllers which implement this protocol.  For example, in Objective C I could do this:

```
-(void)doSomethingWithController:(UIViewController<MyProtocol>*)controller;
```

How do I do this in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    // ...
}

func doSomethingWithController<T: UIViewController where T: MyProtocol> (controller: T) {
    // ...
}

/* Example */
class MyControllerA : UIViewController, MyProtocol {}
class MyControllerB : UIViewController {}

var a = MyControllerA()
var b = MyControllerB()

doSomethingWithController(a) // ok
doSomethingWithController(b) // compile time error
```

Answer (score -2):

I believe you can do that simply by typing the protocol name in place of the type:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func doSomething(viewController: MyProtocol)


}
```

Comment: I guess, ts wants this viewController argument to be kind of UIViewController class, not any object that conforms to MyProtocol protocol